# Python3 - Keep the program running after completing the script

Tags: python

Title basically says it all.
This is my script:

```
    keepProgramRunning = True
a = int(input("Type a value for a: "))
b = int(input("Type a value for b: "))
print("Result when multiplying: ", a*b)
print("Result when dividing: ", a/b)
print("...", a-b)
print("...", a+b)
```

How can i see the results after i typed a value of a and b without cmd automatically closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for another input

```
keepProgramRunning = True
a = int(input("Type a value for a: "))
b = int(input("Type a value for b: "))
print("Result when multiplying: ", a*b)
print("Result when dividing: ", a/b)
print("...", a-b)
print("...", a+b)
input("Press [enter] to continue..")
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to wait for user input

Add this at the end:

```
input("Press enter to close")
```

Alternatively, if you run the script from command line, the window won't disappear after the script ends.

Comment: +1 for (in effect) "don't run the script in its own terminal that closes on exit"